# How do I create a text file (1 gigabyte) containing random characters with UTF-8 character encoding?

Tags: files, unicode, text, random

The following command does not use UTF-8: `head -c 1M </dev/urandom >myfile.txt`

Comment: As long as each char is <=7F, then you have a UTF-8 character

Comment: After executing `head -c 1M </dev/urandom >myfile.txt`, if I open mytext.txt with gedit it says that there are problems with UTF-8 character encoding

Comment: Sorry, I meant that to get valid UTF-8, you must only have single bytes of  <= \x7F or build valid multi-byte UTF-8 sequences. The former is obviously easier from a random perspective.

Comment: Do you want it covering `\u0` to `\U7fffffff` or just `\u0`..`\ud7ff`+ `\ue000`..`\u10ffff` or only those that are currently specified in the latest Unicode spec?

Answer (score 4):

If you want UTF-8 encodings of code points 0 to 0x7FFFFFFF (which the UTF-8 encoding algorithm was originally designed to work on):

```
< /dev/urandom perl -CO -ne '
    BEGIN{$/=\4}
    no warnings "utf8";
    print chr(unpack("L>",$_) & 0x7fffffff)'
```

Nowadays, Unicode is restricted to 0..D7FF, E000..10FFFF (though some of those characters are not assigned, some of which will never be (are defined as non-characters)).

```
< /dev/urandom perl -CO -ne '
    BEGIN{$/=\3}
    no warnings "utf8";
    $c = unpack("L>","\0$_") * 0x10f800 >> 24;
    $c += 0x800 if $c >= 0xd800;
    print chr($c)'
```

If you only want *assigned* characters, you can pipe that to:

```
uconv -x '[:unassigned:]>;'
```

Or change that to:

```
< /dev/urandom perl -CO -ne '
    BEGIN{$/=\3}
    no warnings "utf8";
    $c = unpack("L>","\0$_") * 0x10f800 >> 24;
    $c += 0x800 if $c >= 0xd800;
    $c = chr $c;
    print $c if $c =~ /\P{unassigned}/'
```

You may prefer:

```
             if $c =~ /[\p{Space}\p{Graph}]/ && $c !~ /\p{Co}/
```

To only get graphical and spacing ones (exclude those from the private-use sections).

Now, to get 1GiB of that, you can pipe it to `head -c1G` (assuming GNU `head`), but beware the last character may be cut in the middle.

Answer (score 3):

The most efficient way to create a text file with size 10 MB and UTF-8 character encoding is `base64 /dev/urandom | head -c 10000000 | egrep -ao "\w" | tr -d '\n' > file10MB.txt`

Comment: Is the `egrep` and `tr` necessary?

Comment: That doesn't produce a 10MB file. Also, you either need to remove `base64` or add a `base64 -d` somewhere; what you have now only outputs characters used by the Base64 encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Grep for ASCII (sub-set of UTF-8) chars, on Linux/GNU:

```
dd if=/dev/random bs=1 count=1G | egrep -ao "\w" | tr -d '\n'
```

Comment: `base64`  might be considerably more efficient.

Comment: haha, doh! That's what happens if you over think the question :) You should offer that as an answer :)

Comment: I'm looking for some way to as many UTF8 characters as I can. If I do, I'll post that as answer. :)

Comment: `dd if=/dev/random bs=1 count=10M | egrep -ao "\w" | tr -d '\n' > file10MB.txt` gets stuck. It is too slow.

Comment: @muru you really need to use urandom here, random will get stuck really fast because it needs entropy. This is not fast, but it will get the job done. `dd if=/dev/urandom bs=1 count=1G | egrep -ao "\w" | tr -d '\n'`

Answer (score 0):

If you want non-ASCII characters, then you'll need a way to build valid UTF-8 sequences. The chance that two consecutive bytes yielding a valid UTF-8 is very low.

Instead, this Python script creates random 8 bit values that can be converted in Unicode chars, then written out as UTF-8:

```
import random
import io

char_count = 0

with io.open("random-utf8.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as my_file:

    while char_count <= 1000000 * 1024:
        rand_long = random.getrandbits(8)

        # Ignore control characters
        if rand_long <= 32 or (rand_long <= 0x9F and rand_long > 0x7F):
            continue

        unicode_char = unichr(rand_long)
        my_file.write(unicode_char)
        char_count += 1
```

You could also change it to use a random 16 bit number which would yield non-latin values.

It's not fast but fairly accurate.